# How to get RangeSlider thumb values

Tags: android, rangeslider

I am using RangeSlider in android ,I want display both thumb values. Can anyone help me how I can obtain it?[image]

I want to setText as piece between 20 to 70

Comment: Both the label at the same time?

Comment: yes I picking min and max value and display it as price between range to min  and max

Comment: hi @GabrieleMariotti  please help

Comment: Currently there isn't a way to display always the the label

Comment: can you recommend me library which provides this functionality please

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the library allows you to show this value simultaneously but you can get values of both the thumbs at all times from `rangeSlider.values`

You can then use a custom label on top of the thumbs to display the values at the same time. Other than that, several libraries are available which provide target tooltips on a screen.